# Can a user control the scale of plots in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to generate some simple plots of shapes on the coordinate plane using Wolfram Alpha.  I've had success with plotting the shape, but sometimes the plot output doesn't look nice.  For example, the following plots the vertices of a rhombus on the coordinate plane:

```
Plot {(-5,3), (-1,0), (-1,-5), (-5,-2) (-5,3)}
```

However, the plot is distorted because

1. the y-axis is shown at x = -5; and
2. the scale for the x-axis doesn't match the scale for the y-axis.

As a result, my rhombus doesn't look like a rhombus.  Is there a way to control what portion of the coordinate plane Alpha plots on?  I've tried adding

```
on x:[-8,8] y:[-8,8]
```

at different points in the command, but that won't work.  Anyone know the secret?

Comment: Just specify an AspectRatio. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can: just add [AspectRatio 1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) at the end.

For example:

```
plot cos(arcsin(x)) for 0<=x<=pi/2, plotrange ((0,1),(0,1))
```

[image]

vs.

```
plot cos(arcsin(x)) for 0<=x<=pi/2, plotrange ((0,1),(0,1)), AspectRatio 1
```

[image]

Comment: Better late than never! Thank you and welcome to the site!

Comment: What does `for 0<=x<=pi/2` do? `x` isn't an angle, so this range seems a bit arbitrary to me.

Comment: That's because it _is_ arbitrary, we're just looking at how to control the plot aspect ratio on Wolframalpha, the math itself is irrelevant as long as it's plottable.

Answer (score 0):

No I've tried various combinations, the only thing I can come up with is

`find edges in Plot{(-5,3) (-1,0) (-1,-5) (-5,-2)}, x` and the image output is horrible. Sorry.

Comment: Except "yes", you just need to pass AspectRatio, same as in Mathematica's `Plot` function (note that this worked even back in 2011)